# List<string> to comma separated string and last value without comma

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of strings that contains x amount of items. I would like to create one single string and the items should be comma separated like this:

```
string result = val1, val2, val3, ... valx
```

but I don't want to have the last value followed by comma + space

This is what I tried and the result adds a comma + space at the end of string.

```
  string result = string.Join(", ", myList.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

the result is like this:

```
string result = val1, val2, val3, ... valx,[space]
```

Comment: Why do you use `String.ToString()`?

Comment: Can you confirm that item x is a white-space? Otherwise you would not get the `, ` at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string result = string.Join(", ", myList.Select(x => x.ToString())).TrimEnd(',',' ');
```

**NOTE**: Looks like your input `myList` is a `List of string` so you don't need `ToString()`, just do it like this:

```
string result = string.Join(", ", myList).TrimEnd(',',' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you have a white-space at the end of the list. You really want to remove it from the comma separated lis? That would mean that your item count is less than the list's item count.

```
string result = string.Join(", ", myList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
```

Comment: You forgot `ToArray`. `String.Join` doesn't take `IEnumerable<string>`, only `string[]`.

Comment: @KonradMorawski: It does, from .NET 4 on. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = string.Join(", ", myList.Where(x=>x.Trim() != String.Empty).Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Comment: If `x` is a string, then `.Select(x => x.ToString()))` is unnecessary. If `x` is not a string, then `x.Trim()` will probably not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `myList` for whitepsace

Without WhiteSpace

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
        string result = string.Join(", ", myList.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output:**
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

With WhiteSpace

```
        List<string> myListSpace = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"," " };
        string resultSpace = string.Join(", ", myListSpace.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(resultSpace);
```

**Output:**
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,[space]`

Solution to your problem:

`string result = string.Join(", ", myListSpace.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray());`